# Insert initial data in database

Tags: android, sqlite

So, I think I'm finally ready to start using my database in my app, but...I don't have any data! :o

I've been looking at a lot of different ways to get data in the app:

write insert lines
import a csv (this sounds like fun to me, and hopefully not too painful)
open up the database with software and start tweaking/importing/whatever

I think I want to do a csv. But I don't know where to do it!  In the databasemanager class oncreate? on the individual classes themselves?

Here's my dbmanager class:

```
package com.bluej.movingbuddy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.util.Log;

public class MBDatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Database Version
private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Database Name
private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "dbMovingBuddy";

//items and weights table name
private final static String tblInW = "ItemsAndWeights";
//items and weights table columns
private final static String InWID = "ID";
private final static String InWItem = "Item";
private final static String InWDesc = "Description";
private final static String InWWeightOne = "Weight1";
private final static String InWWeightTwo = "Weight2";
private final static String InWWeightThree = "Weight3";
private final static String InWWeightAvg = "WeightAvg";

//allowances table name
private final static String tblAllowances = "Allowances";
//allowances table columns
private final static String AllowancesID = "ID";
private final static String AllowancesRank = "Rank";
private final static String AllowancesWithDep = "WithDep";
private final static String AllowancesNoDep = "NoDep";

//estimator table name
private final static String tblEstimator = "Estimator";
//estimator table columns
private final static String EstimatorID = "ID";
private final static String EstimatorRoom = "Room";
private final static String EstimatorItem = "Item";
private final static String EstimatorWeight = "Weight";

//inventory table name
private final static String tblInventory = "Inventory";
//inventory table column
private final static String InventoryID = "ID";
private final static String InventoryItem = "Item";
private final static String InventoryWeight = "Weight";
private final static String InventoryValue = "Value";
private final static String InventoryImage1 = "Image1";
private final static String InventoryCondition = "Condition";
private final static String InventoryImage2 = "Image2";
private final static String InventoryNotes = "Notes";
private final static String InventoryMovingInstructions = "MovingInstructions";

//stunt table name
private final static String TABLE_NAME = "database_table";
//stunt table column names
private final static String TABLE_ROW_ID = "id";
private final static String TABLE_ROW_ONE = "table_row_one";
private final static String TABLE_ROW_TWO = "table_row_two";

public MBDatabaseManager(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //This string is used to create the database. It should be changed to suit your needs.

    //create items and weights table
    String dbCreateItemsAndWeights = "create table " +
    tblInW +
    " (" +
    InWID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
    InWItem + " text," +
    InWDesc + " text," +
    InWWeightOne + " integer," +
    InWWeightTwo + " integer," +
    InWWeightThree + " integer," +
    InWWeightAvg + " integer" +
    ");";

    db.execSQL(dbCreateItemsAndWeights);

    //allowances table
    String dbCreateAllowances = "create table " +
    tblAllowances +
    " (" +
    AllowancesID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
    AllowancesRank + " text," +
    AllowancesWithDep + " integer," +
    AllowancesNoDep + " integer" +
    ");";

    db.execSQL(dbCreateAllowances);

    //estimator table
    String dbCreateEstimator = "create table " +
    tblEstimator + 
    " (" +
    EstimatorID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
    EstimatorRoom + " text," +
    EstimatorItem + " integer" +
    EstimatorWeight + " integer" +
    ");";

    db.execSQL(dbCreateEstimator);

    //inventory table
    String dbCreateInventory = "create table " +
    tblInventory + 
    " (" +
    InventoryID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
    InventoryItem + " text," + 
    InventoryWeight + " integer," +
    InventoryValue + " integer," +
    InventoryImage1 + " blob," +
    InventoryCondition + " text," + 
    InventoryImage2 + " blob," + 
    InventoryNotes + " text," +
    InventoryMovingInstructions + " text" +
    ");";

    db.execSQL(dbCreateInventory);      

    //stunt table
    String newTableQueryString = "create table " +
    TABLE_NAME +
    " (" +
    TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
    TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text," +
    TABLE_ROW_TWO + " text" +
    ");";

    db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);        

    //inject data into the tables here? this is probably the best place???


}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tblInW);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tblAllowances);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tblEstimator);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tblInventory);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding a row to the database table

public void addInWItem(String string){


}
public void addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);

    //ask the database object to insert the new data
    try {
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,  null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


//DELETING A ROW FROM THE DATABASE TABLE
//
// This is an example of how to delete a row from a database table
// using this class. In most cases, this method probably does not need to be rewritten.
//
// @param rowID the SQLite database identifier for the row to delete.
//
public void deleteRow(long rowID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // ask the database object to delete the row of given rowID
    try {
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//UPDATING A ROW IN THE DATABASE TABLE
//
// This is an example of how to update a row in the database table
// using this class. You should edit this method to suit your needs.
//
// @param rowID the SQLite database identifier for the row to update.
// @param rowStringOne the new value for the row's first column
// @param rowStringTwo the new value for the row's second column

public void updateRow(long rowID, String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE,  rowStringOne);
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO,  rowStringTwo);

    //ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
    try {
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,  values, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//RETRIEVING A ROW IN THE DATABASE TABLE
//'
// This is an example of how to retrieve a row from a database table using this class. You should edit this method to suit your needs.
//
// @param rowID the id of the row to retrieve
// @return an array containing the data from the row

public ArrayList<Object> getRowAsArray(long rowID){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //create an array list to store data from the database row.
    //I would recommend creating a JavaBean compliant object 
    //to store this data instead. That way you can ensure data types are correct.
    ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Cursor cursor;

    try {
        // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
        // the cursor object stores the information collected from the 
        // database and is used to iterate through the data.
        cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_NAME,
                new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO },
                TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        //move the pointer to position zero in the cursor.
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
        // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.

        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            do{

                rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));

              } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

        //let java know that you are through with the cursor.
        cursor.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //return the ArrayList containing the given row from the database.
    return rowArray;


    }

//RETRIEVING ALL ROWS FROM THE DATABASE TABLE
//
//This is an example of how to retrieve all data from a database table using this class.
//You should edit this method to suit your needs.
//
// the key is automatically assigned by the database

public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllRowsAsArrays(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    //create an ArrayList that will hold all of the data collected from the database
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

    //this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
    //the cursor object stores the information collected from the database and is used to iterate through the data.
    Cursor cursor;

    try{
        //ask the database object to create the cursor.
        cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO},
                null, null, null, null, null
                );

        //move the cursor's pointer to position zero.
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //if there is data after the current cursor position add it to the ArrayList.
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

            do
            {
                ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));

                dataArrays.add(dataList);
            } 

            //move the cursor's pointer up one position.
            while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e){

        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from the database.
    return dataArrays;
}

 }
```

So, after I write the table sql and execute it, is that where I should start filling up data?

First bit of database interactivity I'm going to have is populating a spinner on another class. Should I populate the spinner on that class, or in here? I guess I haven't really found WHERE people start putting data in, just different ways people do it.

What's the best practice?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using a db? I tend to avoid them, unless they are needed, becaus it is a complex process and there is a lot maintenance required. They are great tools and very powerful, but if you don't have a lot of data, there are other, simpler methods that you should explore first.

Comment: I hear you, it is quite complex. I thought it would be much easier, but it really isn't. I guess I could do this all in saved preferences?  I think that's what it's called. SavedPrefs.  Anyway, looking at the table structure above, do you think I could get away with just SharedPrefs? Maybe that's what its called. SharedPrefs? lol

Comment: yeah, shared preferences should work just fine.

Comment: Can I export shared preferences into a flatfile?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It should answer most your questions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html